# How can I maintain both metric and imperial measurement variables?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, internationalization

I'm looking for a best practice, or standard/accepted method of handling both metric and imperial measurements in an app.

I have an iOS app that is currently just in the US market, but I want to internationalize it for other markets. Part of this involves handling both metric and imperial measurements, and displaying the correct one based on localization or preference overrides.

As this app is designed for people traveling, it is likely that a user may want to switch between one system and the other depending on what country they are currently in, so I will need to manage both sets of data.

Since the user could enter the measurements in either system, and want to read the equivalent in the other, I need some way of maintaining them both. My first thought is to create all measurements (length, volume, mass, temp, pressure) as tuples and calculate the missing part when the data is saved. But as this is my first time dealing with two measurement systems at once, I wonder if there's already a standard way of handling such data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Measurement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/) framework. Create a `Measurement` using `init(value:unit:)` and display the results (localized for the current locale settings) in the UI using [`formatted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/3816388-formatted):

E.g.

```swift
let measurement1 = Measurement(value: 3, unit: UnitLength.meters)
let string = measurement1.formatted()
```

Or:

```swift
let measurement2 = Measurement(value: 9, unit: UnitLength.feet)
let string = measurement2.formatted()
```

If you want to allow the user to select imperial/metric within your app and want to show the results in something other than the device’s default locale, you can use [`MeasurementFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/) for fine-grained control over the localization and display of the results in your UI.

Anyway, `Measurment` stores the two properties, `value` and `unit`, in their original values, avoiding any unnecessary rounding that can happen if you were to store the value as an arbitrarily fixed unit of measure in a single `Double`.

FWIW, you can even use this model object (the `Measurement` is `Codable`) in your app. Or, if you want to avoid entangling your backend in the `Measurement` implementation details, you could always store the `value` and the string identifier for the `Unit` as two fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend utilizing the `Measurement` API provided by Apple in the Foundation framework. This provides a way to encapsulate a unit of measure and a double value, offering a range of methods for comparing and converting between different units.

Simple example for distance measurement:

```swift
import Foundation

enum MeasurementSystem {
    case metric
    case imperial
}

class MeasurementManager {
    private var system: MeasurementSystem = .metric

    func changeSystem(to system: MeasurementSystem) {
        self.system = system
    }

    func getUserPreferredDistance(for distanceInMeters: Double) -> String {
        let measurement = Measurement(value: distanceInMeters, unit: UnitLength.meters)

        switch system {
        case .metric:
            let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
            formatter.unitStyle = .short
            formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
            return formatter.string(from: measurement)
        case .imperial:
            let imperialMeasurement = measurement.converted(to: .miles)
            let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
            formatter.unitStyle = .short
            formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
            return formatter.string(from: imperialMeasurement)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code:

1. We have an `enum` `MeasurementSystem` to represent the unit systems we will support: `.metric` and `.imperial`.
2. The `MeasurementManager` class stores the user's current preference for a measurement system. The `changeSystem(to:)` function allows switching the measurement system.
3. The `getUserPreferredDistance(for:)` function receives a distance in meters, creates a `Measurement` object from it, and depending on the user's preferred system, it converts this distance to the appropriate unit and formats it for display.

You can repeat similar procedures for other types of measurements (volume, mass, temperature, etc.) and store the users' preference in persistent storage like `UserDefaults` for future sessions.

With this approach, you're leveraging Swift's built-in functionality for managing and converting between units, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but it seems that this method would be storing the value in one of the systems (metric as shown in your example), then converting to the other system as needed. My issue with that methodology, is that if you enter your value in the secondary system, it will be converted for storage, then converted back for display, potentially leading to rounding errors. It can be frustrating to users when they put in a specific value, that then gets reported back to them differently.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT-generated nonsense (like the other answers you're bulk-posting at the moment)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Jxrgxn/2908bb1f6823341e6cb6b24d72293c5e

In certain scenarios, repeated conversions between units could potentially introduce rounding errors.

An alternative approach is to store the user's input in both systems at the time of entry. This way, no matter what system the user prefers at any given moment, you always have an accurate representation of their original input. Included example

Comment: Technically, there will always be some rounding with the conversion of values from decimal notation to binary floating point, and then there will be another small error if the user wants to use miles but the code forces them to express it in meters. However, the rounding error should be well below any reasonable number of decimal places. (Who wants to see "12.12345678901234 miles"?) You probably want miles and feet, or KM to 3 decimal places, and Double math is plenty precise enough for that with the built in display rounding built into the `Measurement` class.